# Is it possible to translate an auto generated prefix for an object's name?

Tags: custom-object, translation, auto-number

Like in the title. I have, for instance, an object that has it's name as an Auto Number. I can assign a prefix for it just fine in English, but what if I wanted to translate my app, and the prefix would also need to be translated?

Example:

> **LANG**-00001 to **IDI**-00001